# arguments not applicable

Tags: android, arguments

i have this line in my DataDisplay.java to show the data in the database, and i am displaying it into a TextView. but it have this error saying "The method getAllDeals in type DBAdaptor is not applicable for the arguments (TextView, TextView, TextView, TextView, TextView, TextView, TableRow". may someone be kind enough to explain why?

```
dbAdaptor.getAllDeals(idView, shopView, dealView, locationView, websiteView, categoryView, row );
```

this is my getAllDeals portion in DBAdaptor

```
public Cursor getAllDeals()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {KEY_SHOP, KEY_DEAL, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_WEBSITE, 
            KEY_CATEGORY}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept those arguments in your `getAllDeals()` function

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not have any parameters.

From

```
public Cursor getAllDeals()
```

To

```
public Cursor getAllDeals(TextView idView, TextView shopView, etc ...)
```

Comment: there will be error for my cursor = dbAdaptor.getAllDeals(); , do i have to change to cursor = dbAdaptor.getAllDeals(title, title, title, title, title, title, rowTitle); ?

Comment: Why would you have title there 6 times? Have you ever programmed in Java before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the method declaration in your db adapter to:

```
getAllDeals(idView, shopView, dealView, locationView, websiteView, categoryView, row );
```

In your case the Method declaration and method call have different parameters.